# Firefox Dom Inspector 2.x Browser Interface elements

Tags: firefox, xul, dom-inspector

In the old DOM Inspector that had the File menu, I could select the chrome document (browser UI) itself to inspect.  However, in this new one, I can't seem to figure out how to inspect the chrome document. I checked the Enable Browser Debug.

Can someone please tell me how to browse the Dom for the Browser UI?

[Firefox Dom Inspector http://www.dragonwebprogramming.com/websites/temp/dom.gif](http://www.dragonwebprogramming.com/websites/temp/dom.gif)

Comment: Maybe `File` -> `Inspect a chrome document` ?

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear in my question but there is no file menu on the new version. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: What version are using?

Comment: I'm using 2.0.14 on Firefox 30

Comment: Can you show me snapshot of your Dom inspector? I'm using the exact same version on the Firefox with same version but mine has the `file` menu!

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've added a picture of the Dom as a separate window.

Comment: That's the built-in inspector not the extension!

Comment: Is Ctrl+Shft+I to open the built in or add-on Dom Inspector.

When I go to Tools-Web Developer-DOM Inspector it opens the Add-on Inspector but the Ctrl+Shft+I opens the built-in inspector.

Comment: That key combination opens built-in DOM inspector. To open the extension window, you should go through `tools` menu!

Comment: Yes I will use that from now on. Thanks for all your help it was a bit confusing. I would have thought the DOM add-on would take the place of the built-in one but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to `Tools`-> `Web Developer` -> `DOM Inspector`  to open `DOM Inspector`'s dialog, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> just opens built-in inspector!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) from the Web Developer menu to get to the built-in Inspector.

I still prefer the [DOM Inspector add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) add-on personally, as it is easier to do some stuff and allows to e.g. inspect XBL bindings and anonymous nodes properly. You can inspect chrome window by selecting it from the File/Inspect Chrome Document menu.